# How to access the state using Redux RTK in react native app

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-thunk, rtk-query

I'm using Redux RTK query in my react native project and I can't figure out how to access the state without firing the query each time.

I created an api with my `customBaseQuery`

```
const emptySplitApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'api',
  baseQuery: customBaseQuery(),
  endpoints: () => ({})
})
```

I then injected my endpoints.

```
export const userApi = emptySplitApi.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getUser: builder.query<User, GetUserInput>({
      query: (options) => ({
        query: getUserQuery,
        options: options
      })
    })
  }),
  overrideExisting: true
})
```

And configured the store:

```
const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: AsyncStorage
}

const reducers = combineReducers({
  [emptySplitApi.reducerPath]: emptySplitApi.reducer
})

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducers)

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware({ serializableCheck: false }).concat(emptySplitApi.middleware)
})
```

When I open the app I call the getUser API using the redux-generated hook. This works and I get the expected response.

`const { data } = useGetUserQuery(input)`

Now, I need to access the user data in another screen of my app without calling the API again (redux should have cached/persisted the data) but I can't manage to access the state.

I tried the following:

```
const { getUser } = useAppSelector((state) => state.api.queries)
```

but `getUser` is always undefined. However if I print the whole `state` I can see the data.
How can I access the state from anywhere in the app without calling the API again?

Comment: please also add your related reducer

Comment: @novonimo reducer is auto-generated by redux: [configure-the-store](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/overview#configure-the-store)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use your `useGetUserQuery(yourOptions)` everywhere. It will fire only one request to the server, no matter how many times you use it, and the data will be available everywhere.

Comment: got it. That means that I need to store `yourOptions` somewhere and make it available across all the screens/components where I call the `useGetUserQuery(yourOptions)` query. Is that correct?

Comment: If that cannot easily be constructed from available info like props, yes. Of course often just passing the query result via props might also be a more sensible option. There is no "one size fits all".